# How to be sure that a script saved with ANSI is going to work on every client environment?

Tags: notepad++, utf-8, ansi

Long story short. How can I fix users environments, to make them run our scripts using ANSI encode?

The problem is, we send them scripts to run on their databases using ANSI encode.

But some of them are returning to us with this problem:

[image]

We tried to say "please upgrade your software to run our scripts using ANSI encode" but most of them can't do this.

Is there a way for us, developers ( not me at all, I'm the DBA trying to help here ) to do something ?? WE have this problem since ever. we read all the internet and we couldnt fix this issue.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry. this script was made with UTF-8.

Comment: The text in the picture looks like UTF-8 encoded text interpreted as (some version of) ISO 8859. It looks like your users are using UTF-8. How about fixing the problem the other way: you adopt UTF-8 instead of forcing old character encodings on your users. By the way, "ANSI" is not a single encoding, it is an umbrella term for about 20 different encodings.

Comment: Yes sorry Johan, in this case, UTF-8 was used.

Comment: Is your question still current?